# IBM Db2 Clob column to store of text upto the size of 20MB

Tags: java, db2

We are getting a message from upstream system, the average size of message is  2-5KB but in some cases message can be as big as 20 MB. We need to store message in a table for audit purposes. Database is IBM DB2 9.7 and column type is CLOB. I have couple of questions:

- In DB2 the default size of CLOB column is 1MB, is it ok to increase the size of column to 20 MB.
- Does database allocate space according to actual data size or column size, so let's say if message size is 5KB how much space will be allocated to the row?
- Is there any other better way to store such data in db2 relation database so size of message is not a constraint. we want to use relational  database only.

Thanks

Comment: did you try to to search for such information?

Comment: Yes, i did and according to ibm i can increase the size but didn't find if there will be any downside of doing which i am trying to explore here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOBs will use some more space than the original "message" but a 5KB message will need far less storage than a 20MB one.

Check out LOB inlining for such scenarios.
Using inlining will allow to store snmall lobs with the data (and therefore improving IO performance) and above a certain size it will stored in the lobspace.

This can be achieved by adding an INLINE LENGTH to your column definition of the table. LOBs up to this value will be stored with the data and larger ones automatically in the LOBSPACE.
Performnace experiences with this functionality are very good.

see also a best practies information
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W7c1e3103820b_4d9e_add6_b5ade3280dcb/page/Inline+LOBs+%28Large+Objects%29

Comment: Yes, i am using inline to store any object smaller thank 27K un same row.